# Find missed max and min value in a sequence of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, I have a sequence of numbers: **{1, 2, 5, 7}**.
I need to find the smallest and the biggest one, which are missed in this sequence (min=3 and max=6 for this example). Values can also be negative.
Here is my solution, but it doesn't pass on extra checking database (Wrong number of records (less by 1)), so I can't say what is exactly wrong. I also tried versions with LEFT OUTER JOIN and EXCEPT predicates - same problem. Please, help me to improve my solution.

```
WITH AA AS (SELECT MAX(Q_ID) MX
            FROM UTQ),
   
     BB AS (SELECT MIN(Q_ID) CODE
            FROM UTQ
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT CODE + 1
            FROM BB
            WHERE CODE < (SELECT MX
                          FROM AA)
            )

SELECT MIN(CODE) MIN_RES, MAX(CODE) MAX_RES
FROM BB
WHERE CODE NOT IN (SELECT Q_ID
                   FROM UTQ)
```

Comment: Which table has the numbers you want to check and which contains numbers the missing ones? `BB` or `UTQ`

Comment: @Charlieface `UTQ` has a start sequence of numbers with missings. `BB` is created by recursion and contains all numbers (without missings) from minimum number of `UTQ` to maximum.

Comment: This query works fine with your sample data. Without seeing data that causes it to fail, it's almost impossible to debug the problem.

Comment: Sorry, missed the recursion. What results does this give? It looks correct, although there are much more efficient methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select min(q_id + 1)
from utq
where not exists (select 1 from utq utq2 where utq2.q_id = utq.id + 1)
union all
select max(q_id - 1)
from utq
where not exists (select 1 from utq utq2 where utq2.q_id = utq.id - 1);
```

You can also use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select min(case when next_q_id <> q_id + 1 then q_id + 1 end),
       max(case when prev_q_id <> q_id - 1 then q_id - 1 end)
from (select utq.*,
             lag(q_id) over (order by q_id) as prev_q_id,
             lead(q_id) over (order by q_id) as next_q_id
      from utq
     ) utq;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like following using `LEAD`

```
SELECT MIN(Q_ID + 1) AS MinValue
      ,MAX(Q_ID + 1) AS MaxValue
FROM (
    SELECT *,LEAD(Q_ID) OVER (ORDER BY Q_ID) NQ_ID
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(5),(7)) v(Q_ID)
    ) t
WHERE NQ_ID - Q_ID <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A [tally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) based method seems like a good approach here.  Especially if the sequences are large.

The first `CTE` summarizes the maximum and minimum q_id's in the test table.  The second `CTE` selects the missing integers by generating the complete sequence (using the fnNumbers tvf) between the minimum and maximum q_id values and comparing `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to the original sequence.  Something like this.

numbers function

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

data and query

```
drop table if exists #seq;
go
create table #seq(
  q_id          int unique not null);

insert #seq values (1),(2),(5),(7);

with
max_min_cte(max_q, min_q) as (
    select max(q_id), min(q_id)
    from #seq),
missing_cte(q_id) as (
    select mm.min_q+fn.n
    from max_min_cte mm
         cross apply dbo.fnNumbers(0, mm.max_q-mm.min_q) fn
    where not exists (select 1
                      from #seq s
                      where (mm.min_q+fn.n)=s.q_id))
select max(q_id) max_missing, min(q_id) min_missing
from missing_cte;
```

output

```
max_missing min_missing
6           3
```